# revoke forbiddance to send Apple events to System Events

Tags: homebrew, catalina, git

I have been using Gitk provided by Git provided by Homebrew with success, for several years.

A couple of days ago, it suddenly prompted a security window when called.

I did not allow access, hoping I would be able to change my mind.

Now trying to start Gitk will always cause:

```
$ gitk --all
Error in startup script: 58:103: execution error: Not authorised to send Apple events to System Events. (-1743)
    while executing
"exec osascript -e [format {
        tell application "System Events"
            set frontmost of processes whose unix id is %d to true
        end te..."
    invoked from within
"if {[tk windowingsystem] eq "aqua"} {
    exec osascript -e [format {
        tell application "System Events"
            set frontmost of processes ..."
    (file "/usr/local/bin/gitk" line 12237)
$ _
```

I would need to revoke that forbiddance.

I have removed Git and reinstalled:

```
$ brew remove --force git && brew install git
```

That didn't solve the case<sup>1</sup>. Force was used in order to remove all versions.

If I don't fix this, I'd need to get used to either Tig or Sourcetree or some other alternative, with an impact in immediate productivity.

<sub>1: After reinstalling, error is the same, just moved to line 12212. That's because I use [taint patches](//gist.github.com/uprego/600445d4f4633113c3ed0ff24994bbed) on top of official Gitk. As you can see, those patches are unrelated to the cause, so please don't let it make you focus away from the actual issue, which is 100% macOS materials.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much in advance. - I would thank keeping from *not needed* comment flags until question is answered. :(

Comment: I had looked, couldn't find anything related; looked again, still can't find a good lead to a fix.

Comment: That worked and relieves a large pain!

Comment: @user3439894 please promote your comment to answer..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check setting under: **System Preferences** > **Security** & **Privacy** > **Privacy**

If you find nothing there, then in **Terminal**, read the *man page* for: `tccutil`

```
man tccutil
```

You can use the following *command* to reset all permissions you've set on **AppleEvents**:

```
tccutil reset AppleEvents
```

Note that after doing so, you'll have to respond to all previous queries that may come forward again.

---

<sub>Note: A few years back there was a project IIRC on GitHub that allowed reading the *privacy database* and targeting specific occurrences of a set permission, but I think changes in macOS Mojave crippled it. It might be worth doing a bit of googling if you'er looking to target just a specific occurrence of an app permission that is not available in the GUI.</sub>

Comment: Worked after resetting the AppleEvents

Comment: I've tried this on Catalina and it didn't work. If I run this command in Terminal:

strings /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC | grep kTCCService

I can see the following so is AppleEvents no longer resettable?

%s{public}: service kTCCServiceAppleEvents is not supported by this function

Answer (score 6):

I've hit this issue several times and today I found a solution described @ [macobserver](https://www.macobserver.com/community/mac-questions/how-to-deal-with-not-autorized-to-send-apple-events-to-finder-error-when-running-scripts/#post-5145) by [Dave Hamilton](https://www.macobserver.com/community/profile/davehamilton/), so the credit belongs to Dave.

### My setup is:

macOS Mojave, Macport and ohmyzsh, XQuartz

### Issue:

As described above, when I run `$> gitk`, I got same failure (I cannot recall if I was ever been prompted, but this [thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/CC28BF55-9334-42A8-8A40-5D3E54BF8961@me.com/T/) makes me believe I could not).

```
Error in startup script: 58:102: execution error: Not authorised to send Apple events to System Events. (-1743)
    while executing
"exec osascript -e [format {
        tell application "System Events"
            set frontmost of processes whose unix id is %d to true
        end te..."
    invoked from within
"if {[tk windowingsystem] eq "aqua"} {
    exec osascript -e [format {
        tell application "System Events"
            set frontmost of processes ..."
    (file "/opt/local/bin/gitk" line 12261)
```

The accepted answer from [@user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894) gave me some hope, but I didn't realise until I found Dave's post permissions are divided into groups like *Accessibility* (the one I was always looking into), and *Automation* which is where the solution hides.

### Fix

1. Open *System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy* and there
2. Select *Automation* group from the left hand side panel
3. Spot unchecked Terminal or similar application
   [image]
4. Check it & close the System Preferences window
5. Try to run `gitk` again.
   Voalà...
   [image]